# COBOL Screen Section

Tags: cobol

We have RM COBOL utility which has a screen section, which takes input from the user. This input can be a Function key as well. (like F1, F2, etc)

I am trying to automate it using shell scripting, is it possible to pass these function key parameters to screen-section input?

Comment: The question is hard to answer without access to RM COBOL.
Does it work if you put stdin via redirection? What OS and environment (some script? shell? bash? cmd? powershell?) does the test run?

Comment: How to pass function keys to this. I am using Unix OS . Using shell script. 
Passing function key I am not aware how to do via shell script

Comment: The question is mainly how the RM/COBOL runtime expect those. Does it work when you use an `ACCEPT SOME-TEXT` and run the program with `prog < 'some text
' <- there's a line break here, the comments just remove the "formatting" = does the program continue and has this data?

Comment: The topic is not about `SCRREN SECTION`, it is about how to send function key input to your program

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that RM COBOL works similarly to AcuCobol, yes.

But ... how is a function key represented?  Well, for a particular terminal, it will produce a character or a stream of characters to represent that function key.  Different terminals (and I'm including terminal emulators here) send different values for function keys, so you'll need to identify what kind of terminal is being used.  Another complicating thing is that some terminals send different values for function keys depending on what mode the terminal is in.

My suggestions:

1. Record what $TERM is set to and be sure to set that environment variable to the same value in the script.
2. Use the `script` utility to record the input and output of the program to determine what the terminal sends when you press the function key.  Then you can use that value in your script.